# Why isn't my JS slider working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm new to HTML/CSS, I recently purchased a bootstrap theme and I'm trying to create my own homepage using segments of HTML code they provided.

I copy/pasted a section of code and the file paths for the JS but it doesn't work at all. The assets(text, images, videos) all appear but none of it is styled and it's all static. Neither the CSS nor the JS is working on that segment.

**This is a live demo of how it's supposed to look:**

http://htmlstream.com/preview/unify-v1.7/index.html

This is how mine looks currently:

http://i.gyazo.com/7f8caf3b13c10c3dbfd340afd3fcb1db.png

**This is the HTML segment for the slider:**

```
<!--=== Slider ===-->
    <div class="slider-inner">
        <div id="da-slider" class="da-slider">
            <div class="da-slide">
                <h2><i>CLEAN &amp; FRESH</i> <br /> <i>FULLY RESPONSIVE</i> <br /> <i>DESIGN</i></h2>
                <p><i>Lorem ipsum dolor amet</i> <br /> <i>tempor incididunt ut</i> <br /> <i>veniam omnis </i></p>
                <div class="da-img"><img class="img-responsive" src="assets/plugins/parallax-slider/img/1.png" alt=""></div>
            </div>
            <div class="da-slide">
                <h2><i>RESPONSIVE VIDEO</i> <br /> <i>SUPPORT AND</i> <br /> <i>MANY MORE</i></h2>
                <p><i>Lorem ipsum dolor amet</i> <br /> <i>tempor incididunt ut</i></p>
                <div class="da-img">
                    <iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/47911018" width="530" height="300" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe> 
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="da-slide">
                <h2><i>USING BEST WEB</i> <br /> <i>SOLUTIONS WITH</i> <br /> <i>HTML5/CSS3</i></h2>
                <p><i>Lorem ipsum dolor amet</i> <br /> <i>tempor incididunt ut</i> <br /> <i>veniam omnis </i></p>
                <div class="da-img"><img src="assets/plugins/parallax-slider/img/html5andcss3.png" alt="image01" /></div>
            </div>
            <div class="da-arrows">
                <span class="da-arrows-prev"></span>
                <span class="da-arrows-next"></span>        
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!--/slider-->
    <!--=== End Slider ===-->
```

**This is the HEAD section of my HTML file:**

```
<head>
<title>Ideal Improvements South West LTD | Home</title>

<!-- Meta -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<!-- Favicon -->
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">

<!-- Web Fonts -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600&amp;subset=cyrillic,latin">

<!-- CSS Global Compulsory -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">

<!-- CSS Header and Footer -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/headers/header-v3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/footers/footer-v1.css">

<!-- CSS Implementing Plugins -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/animate.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/line-icons/line-icons.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<!-- CSS Theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/theme-colors/default.css" />

<!-- CSS Customization -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/custom.css">
```

**This is the JS section at the bottom of my file:**

```
    <!-- JS Global Compulsory -->           
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- JS Implementing Plugins -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/back-to-top.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/smoothScroll.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/parallax-slider/js/modernizr.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/parallax-slider/js/jquery.cslider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/owl-carousel/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>
<!-- JS Customization -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/custom.js"></script>
<!-- JS Page Level -->           
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/plugins/owl-carousel.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/plugins/parallax-slider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        App.init();
        OwlCarousel.initOwlCarousel();        
        StyleSwitcher.initStyleSwitcher();      
        ParallaxSlider.initParallaxSlider();
    });
</script>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="assets/plugins/respond.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/plugins/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/plugins/placeholder-IE-fixes.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

I get 7 errors in the chrome dev tools console. 4 are "Uncaught syntaxerror: unexpected token illegal"
2 are "failed to load resource: err_cache_missing and err_file_not_found (The cache one links to the vimeo video link and the file not found links to google fonts.)
The last is "uncaught referenceerror: style switcher is not defined" I believe this is to do with the way I copied some of the code, if you look at the live demo site it has a style switcher on the top right corner.

I took one of the demo html files and put it into my site director and it accesses the JS and CSS fine using the same file paths.

Comment: Could you please take a screenshot of your console and errors.

Comment: Here it is, I tried to include it in the original post but I don't have enough reputation.

http://i.gyazo.com/febdf7bb550daf1e6d38d40fd4a97bd5.png

Comment: There seem to be files missing, plus there are many spaces on the script src elements that shouldn't be there. Do you have all the libraries?

Comment: I believe the spaces in the code here are formatting errors by me, the spaces don't appear in my html file. What do you mean by the libraries?

Would it help if I compress and upload my site file so everyone can access the source code?

Comment: I edited the original post and fixed all the code, the spaces before were a formatting error.

Comment: In network tab (browser console) are all files downloaded correctly? First let's finish debate on resource import, then we could go further.

Answer (score 0):

```
hello you seen your code properly i think something wrong 

<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/parallax-  slider/js/modernizr.js"></script>

Space between js name i think this is problem.

or anything else please share your website link or demo code slider
```

Comment: Sorry that was my fault while formatting. The code doesn't have spaces in the original file:

http://i.gyazo.com/5d440a947f3629087b07913425352289.png

Comment: you can download  all js and css and set by directory structure in your computer